# NodeJS arrays synchronous?

Tags: arrays, node.js

```
var membersStatArray = [];
membersArray.forEach(function(member) {
    db.doneTodo
        .find({ 'victor._id': member._id })
        .then((arrayOfUserVictories) => {
            membersStatArray.push({
                email: member.email,
                victories: arrayOfUserVictories.length
            });
        })
});
console.log(membersStatArray);
```

**It doesnt** matter what db is.

I know NodeJS is asynchronous but then what is a way of adding to the array and THEN printing the array?

What happens now is,

```
console.log(membersStatArray) --> []
```

Because it takes the empty array.

What is way past this?

Comment: node.js arrays are `synchronous`, but db calls aren't/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code so that it uses [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to collect all the promises into a single promise, which will resolve when all of the individual promises have resolved:

```
Promise.all(membersArray.map((member) => {
    return db
        .doneTodo
        .find({'victor._id': member._id})
        .then((userVictories) => ({
            email: member.email,
            victories: userVictories.length
        }));
})).then((memberStats) => {
    console.log(membersStats);
});
```

Comment: This is a new method for me. What is this "map?"

Comment: It's defined in the documentation under [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: Thanks for guiding me through! Why do I need the "return" signs?

Comment: The first return statement returns the promise that results from the chain of functions there, and deposits it into a new array (as specified by map). The second return statement is used to change what the promise returns so that they will resolve with the object format you want.

Comment: The documentation for [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Promise.prototype.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) both describe what's done with the return value of their callbacks as well.

Comment: so whenever I use a "then" call I need to have "return" first?

Comment: But this works fine:` db.group.addUserToGroup(groupIDToJoin, userID, userEmail).then(() => {
        res.status(200).send();
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(400).send()
    });` (from another snippet) without Return

Comment: You don't need to return anything from the callback if you're finished using the value and don't need to access the value in any later callbacks.

Comment: I'm just confused about returning the "db statement." When do I need to return db.... and when I not need to?

Comment: You're not returning the `db`, you're returning the promise that comes from the end of that chain of dots. I basically rewrote the 3rd line of the code in your question into a more readable format.

Comment: Ok. Why do I need the return in front of the db then? Why isnt it enough to have the return in front of the final object?

Comment: You also need to return the promise itself, so that `map` can deposit it into the new array the `map` creates.

Comment: So return db.find or return db.update.. RETURN the (then) part?  Then why does this work without return -->  `db.user.findOne({_id: id}).then((friend) => {
       ...
    });`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you don't return the promise, then `Promise.all` will be receiving an array of `undefined` values. The code in the comment you just posted isn't using the promise beyond that `then` statement.

Comment: So the return is for Promise.all? Where can I read on this? I feel I am lacking in something fundamental about promises

Comment: The `map` returns an array of promises which gets fed directly into the parameter for `Promise.all`. I've linked to the documentation throughout my comments for you to read more about each of those functions

Comment: I get that map (x -> y) takes a value and then replaces it with the object. The only trouble I have is understanding where and why we use return in the db.

Comment: If we dont put return in front of db, why does that give undefined array?

Comment: A function with no `return` statement returns `undefined` in JavaScript. If there's no return statement, the map will be (x -> undefined) instead of (x -> y)

Comment: I ran this: `db.user.findOne({_id: '5866b30be493368fcf73fadb'}).then((friend) => {
        console.log(friend);
        res.status(205).send();
    });` with and without return and it literally outputs the exactly same thing.

Comment: There is no `map` being used in that code. The `return` is required because of what `map` uses it for.

Comment: I've edited to highlight the return statement which is used by `map`

Comment: While I really really do appreciate you trying to help me  out, I needed to post this as a question so I could get a completely thorough answer from step 0

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async` as well.

```
var async = require("async");
var membersStatArray = [];

async.each(membersArray,
  function(member, callback){
    db.doneTodo.find({'victor._id': member._id}).then((arrayOfUserVictories) =>{
        membersStatArray.push({email: member.email, victories: arrayOfUserVictories.length});
        callback();
    })
  },
  function(err){
      console.log(membersStatArray);
  }
);
```